How long have people been predicting the collapse of the family?
During my studies, I have happened to come across the article Women’s Brains by Stephen Jay Gould, about misogyny throughout history. Within it, Gould quotes French philosopher Gustave Le Bon, who in 1879 says,

A desire to give [women] the same education, and, as a consequence, to propose the same goals for them, is a dangerous chimera .... The day when, misunderstanding the inferior occupations which nature has given her, women leave the home and take part in our battles; on this day a social revolution will begin, and everything that maintains the sacred ties of the family will disappear.

Then Gould adds, "Sound familiar?"
Which indeed, the latter part sounds familiar in the context of modern arguments against gay marriage. Through a conventional web search, I could not find an answer, thus why I am asking here: just how long have people been predicting the collapse of the family/marriage because of change?

Seems like this should be on the History SE.

I don't understand what is so specific about gay marriage in the quote. It's more about feminism/emancipation, or do I understand it wrongly? The gay marriage movement is for marriage, not against it.

Voting to close: While there is a political context to the question, the actual specific question is more about sociology and history than politics because this has been the subject of not only philosophical discussions but also religious. As such, this Q is apt for history.SE.

@Allure: of Philosophy SE, since it's a Q about the history of a (vague) idea. Considering that the most upvoted answer starts with Plato, I'm probably not wrong.

The fact that the death of the family has been predicted at certain times in the past doesn't itself mean much because the family actually can collapse only to recover again. The Black Plague was bad for families, but that didn't last forever. Divorce and out of wedlock birth in the U.S. were much lower in 1955 (and had no major racial or social class divides) than it is now. The Moynihan report pointed out major shifts in black families in the U.S. in the 1960s and other ethnicities followed suit later. Right now in the U.S. college educated couples are doing great, others, not so much.


Question:
How long have people been predicting the collapse of the family?

Predicting the collapse of the family, observing it's collapse or generally worrying about the future of society because young people are just not up to the task?
The Greek philosopher Plato (427 – 348 BC) in his vision of a futuristic ideal society predicted the decline of the traditional family. In The Republic, Plato outlines an ideal society in which the traditional family structure is replaced by communal living arrangements, especially among the ruling class (the "guardians"). In this model, children are raised communally, and biological parentage is less important. Plato suggests that such a structure would create a more just and unified society, where personal loyalties to family do not interfere with loyalty to the state.

Plato:
And on the young men, surely, who excel in war and other pursuits we must bestow honors and prizes, and, in particular, the opportunity of more frequent intercourse with the women, which will at the same time be a plausible pretext for having them beget as many of the children as possible.” “Right.” “And the children thus born will be taken over by the officials appointed for this, men or women or both, since, I take it, the official posts too are common to women and men. [460c] The offspring of the good, I suppose, they will take to the pen or créche, to certain nurses who live apart in a quarter of the city, but the offspring of the inferior, and any of those of the other sort who are born defective, they will properly dispose of in secret,2 so that no one will know what has become of them. (!!)

The Greek historian Polybius (circa 200–118 BCE). In his work The Histories, Polybius examined the rise and fall of states, particularly focusing on the Roman Republic. While he primarily analyzed political and military causes of Rome's success, he also commented on social issues, including the decline of family structures and values.

Polybius
For this evil grew upon us rapidly, and without attracting attention, by our men becoming perverted to a passion for show and money and the pleasures of an idle life, and accordingly either not marrying at all, or, if they did marry, refusing to rear the children that were born, or at most one or two out of a great number, for the sake of leaving them well off or bringing them up in extravagant luxury. For when there are only one or two sons, it is evident that, if war or pestilence carries off one, the houses must be left heirless: and, like swarms of bees, little by little the cities become sparsely inhabited and weak. On this subject there is no need to ask the gods how we are to be relieved from such a curse: for anyone in the world will tell you that it is by the men themselves if possible, changing their objects of ambition; or, if that cannot be done, by passing laws for the preservation of infants.

As for worrying for the future based on how terrible young people are relative to their observing elders.

Aristotle Rhetoric 2 chapter 12
They [Young People] have exalted notions, because they have not been humbled by life or learned its necessary limitations; moreover, their hopeful disposition makes them think themselves equal to great things -- and that means having exalted notions. They would always rather do noble deeds than useful ones: Their lives are regulated more by moral feeling than by reasoning -- all their mistakes are in the direction of doing things excessively and vehemently. They overdo everything -- they love too much, hate too much, and the same with everything else.


Basically as far back as we have records of persuasive/polemic writing, and in essentially every society where a reasonable body of such works have survived: we have records of this prediction. One may infer a degree of universality from this.

I think the small difference here is that Plato saw this as something positive.

It is described in The Communist Manifesto as a highly positive principle. It was assumed, social institutions will take over children.
The Communist Manifesto by Karl Marx and Friedrich Engels was first published on February 21, 1848. It was a key document in the history of socialist and communist movements.

On what foundation is the present family, the bourgeois family, based? On capital, on private gain. In its completely developed form, this family exists only among the bourgeoisie; but this state of things finds its complement in the practical absence of the family among the proletarians, and in public prostitution.
The bourgeois family will vanish as a matter of course when its complement vanishes, and both will vanish with the vanishing of capital.


note that Marx predicts, and praises, the idea of the collapse of the bourgeois family, not the family as a whole

@Tristan Fair, but hasn't the bourgeois family already destroyed "the family" as a whole. Like the large multigenerational families living together have seen a major decline with the advent of the nuclear family.

@haxor789 sure, but the destruction of the bourgeois family wouldn't (necessarily) preclude instituting a new model of the family, so it isn't equivalent to the collapse of the family as a whole

Ezra and Nehemiah were both concerned with Judaism going out of existence due to intermarriage.  This was about 450 BCE or so.
This had happened to the ten northern tribes after getting conquered by the Assyrians in 722 BCE.
In the early 1960s, Look magazine predicted that Jewish families would disappear by 1970.  That did not happen,  but look what happened to Look.

That doesn't seem to pertain directly to the collapse of the family, but of a specific culture, so doesn't seem to answer the question

Tristan: I disagree with you.  ALL of the answers are from writers who were thinking about their own cultures.  For example, Marx: Bourgeoisie and capitalism are European concepts.  In any event, the question was "just how long have people been predicting the collapse of the family/marriage because of change?".  Ezra and Nehemia are responding to the change of intermarriage.  Jews have been predicting that collapse for 2500 years.
You and I must agree to disagree.  I defer to the OP if my answer is acceptable.
